# My new D-Link router won't let my phones connect to it wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I already bought the Netgear CM400-1AZNAS modem and the D-Link DIR-813 AC750 router from Amazon. I think they will be enough or probably better than my current combined modem and router from Xfinity which is a TG862G/CT. The problem is that I already contacted Xfinity and it's good to their part. My modem works fine (I connected it directly to my dekstop) and all websites are working. However, when I connect the modem to the router, everything drives me insane. I first got the problem that while I'm in my desktop, I can't browse several websites like IGN, my school's website, ThePirateBay, other support forums. However, it works perfectly on Facebook, YouTube, and Google. I decided to go to my router's settings, and change it from "Wireless Router" to "AP mode." Everything's good now, all sites are working and I was able to visit this site. BUT, I can't seem to connect my phones wirelessly. I tried entering the RIGHT password but no use. There's another computer(laptop) in my living room which is connected (wired) and I also won't be able to get it connected. Please help. What should I do? This is already driving me insane! I flushed the DNS, and rebooted resetted everything.

Comment: Telling us that you can't do something doesn't tell us anything. Why can't you? What happens when you try?

Comment: This is a **very** broad question...

Answer (score 1):

Your modem is just a modem. And if you set your router to AP mode, then it's just an access point. That means you have no router. Without a router, you can't have more than one device using your Internet connection. That explains why your phones don't work.

If you want help troubleshooting the configuration that should work, you'll have to tell us what goes wrong with that configuration. Telling us that you "can't do" something doesn't help us. We need to know *why* you can't do. We need to know which steps work and which don't. And we need to know precisely *how* the step that failed actually failed.